# Sharepoint list validation syntax question?

Tags: validation, formula

I'm trying to get this SharePoint list validation formula to work.

I ultimately want to make sure the date value in my [Date of Appointment] column is greater than the date value in my [Date Followed-Up] column, if [Date Followed-Up] is filled in.

Here's what I tried:

```
=IF(AND([Date Followed-Up]<>"", [Date of Appointment]>[Date Followed-Up]), [Date of Appointment], "Needs updating")
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The list validation needs simply to return TRUE for the validation to pass.

There is no need for your IF:

```
=AND([Date Followed-Up]<>"", [Date of Appointment]>[Date Followed-Up])
```

I'm not sure if comparing your field with "" will work though, I would try with the ISBLANK:

```
=OR(ISBLANK([Date Followed-Up]),[Date of Appointment]>[Date Followed-Up])
```

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint list validation the result of your formula should be `true/false`.

For your case, try using below formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date Followed-Up]), true, [Date of Appointment]>[Date Followed-Up])
```

This will ensure that if `Date Followed-Up` is blank then it should allow you to add/edit the list item.

Or simply you can use the formula like below:

```
=OR(ISBLANK([Date Followed-Up]), [Date of Appointment] > [Date Followed-Up])
```

**Official documentations**:

1. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).
2. [IS functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087).
3. [OR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/or-function-fa430d29-4638-404e-8219-9ff07016601f).